# Are GIS tools suitable for physical capacity and placement management?

Tags: postgis, geometry, mysql-spatial, location-allocation

I'm a complete newbie to GIS systems, I've been watching some introductory videos about GIS but I'm not yet sure if GIS tools are the right tool for solving my problem.

I have a database with thousands of "locations". Locations are usually rectangular and of varying sizes. I also have "contents" of varying sizes that must be placed inside a location. Contents are not always rectangular but i think that using the minimun bounding rectangle might be acceptable.

Keeping track of the free space measured in square units its trivial but of course there might be many cases where the remaining space can not be used due to the geometry of the content.

Could a GIS database like Mysql's spatial extensions or postgis answer to a question like "Which of the locations has enough suitable free space for the new content?"

Comment: Yes. It is very easy to do intersections, differences, unions, etc between different geometric objects and report things like area, width/height of the result. If you could make the question slightly more specific, ie, more along the lines of the last sentence, you will get a better answer.

Comment: GIS tools are suitable for all manner of spatial management tasks, but spatially enabled databases are just a pale shadow of GIS software capabilities.

Comment: @Vince, your comment voices a strong opinion on spatial databases but lacks arguments. Also, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Since you say you are a complete newbie, another thing to consider is the learning curve versus how much time you have to do the project.